# Open egit code comparison in floating tab rather than splitscreen

Tags: eclipse, egit

When using Eclipse (Mars), I often use the *Git staging* view maximized. When I double click on an entry, I want the comparison view floating over the maximized view.

This is how I do it:

1. Go to *Git staging* view.
2. Maximize it (Ctrl+M).
3. ***Git staging* fills the screen**.
4. Double click on entry.
5. ***Compare current and index* view starts in a splitscreen, pushing *Git staging* to the lower third of the screen**.
6. Set focus to *Git staging* view.
7. Press Ctrl+M again.
8. **Original Layout restored**.
9. Press Ctrl+M yet again.
10. ***Git staging* fills the screen**.
11. Double click on entry again.
12. ***Compare current and index* view starts in an overlay**.

Is there any way to configure Eclipse in order to avoid having to go through steps 5 to 11?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the comparison editor forcely opens in a splitscreen every time it gets *started* and can be shown in a floating tab when it's only getting *updated*.

Thus, a workaround is to get into the habit of not closing it and keeping it opened in the back all the time.